# Database design for internal Messaging (like facebook message)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

In the following database design, how do I mark an unread message, so we know who read the message either the sender and recipient?

(ie When person X sends a message to person Y, the message will be marked as unread for person Y until person Y reads the message, but its marked as read for person X because he sent the message).

**MESSAGE**

- Id (PK)
- Subject
- Content
- MessageTypeId (FK) - Message, Update (global board-cast), notifications etc
- UserId (FK) - creator
- CreateDate
- ReadDate

**MESSAGE_COMMENT**

- Id (PK)
- MessageId (FK)
- Content
- UserId (FK) - creator
- CreatedDate

---

**USER**

- FirstName
- LastName
- Username
- Password
- IsActive
- etc...etc...

**MESSAGE_TYPE**

- Id
- Code
- Name

EDIT: it seems like the design is incomplete.

Comment: Can you add tables/columns to the design or do you have to solve it just with what is here?

Comment: can change existing or add additional tables/columns.

Comment: You can update the question and add the structure of tables `User` and `Type` that the `UserId` and the `TypedId` reference.

Comment: From these 2 tables, I don't see how to identify which users have received a message.  In traditional email systems you would need this, though I haven't used Facebook Messages so maybe not.  At a minimum though the model needs to support an inbox concept.  Once you have that, it should be easier to see how you might want to mark a message as read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Read` table which links user ID and message ID.  When a message is created the application automatically puts in the UserID of the creator and the MessageID.  Then when the receiver reads the message it records the ReceiverID and the MessageId.

So while there is no record for ReceiverID and MessageID, the message will appear unread for the receiver.

Comment: what about for message comment (the response)?

Comment: What about for multiple recipients?

Comment: The above solution applies for multiple recipients - there's still only one sender, and each recipient would follow the same logic so there's actually no need to think of that as a different issue.

Comment: In terms of message comments I personally think that you could drop the Message_Comment table.  You could add a 'CommentToMessageId' field in the Message table which specifies on which message (if any) this message is a comment.  Then, again, the above solution would cover both cases.

Comment: the comment table, could very well be dropped. Yes.